# Want to add google ads code in editor in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-6

I want to add google ads code in a content type but when I try to do this editor remove `ins` tags from  ads. I am using ck-Editor in Drupal 7.x

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't check adding Google Ads code in CK-editor but if "tags got removed" is only your problem you can fix this by following the below instructions.

```
1. Navigate to admin->configurations->Text Formats.
2. Select a format FilterHTML/FullHTML for change its configurations.
3. On the edit form you will be able to insert tags which you want to allow by CK-editor from you editors source code.
```

[image]

This will appear by default, but if not for you please select the check box options "Limit allowed HTML tags" above in the form. Now clear you cache and check. It might resolve your issue.